# Как в Linux запускать программу с одними и теми же виртуальными адресами?

Tags: c++, linux, c

Допустим, есть некий `./a.out` (получен из Си), который выводит адрес, возвращаемый первым же `malloc` (естественно, на пути к нему всегда выполняются одни и те же действия).

При каждом запуске мы видим разные числа
 - это особенность Linux (м.б. и в других системах тоже реализовано) запускать программу так, чтобы стек, куча и область для mapping-а файлов размещались по случайным адресам).

А вот если смотреть в gdb или запустить этот `./a.out` в valgrind, то увидим один и тот же адрес.

Вопрос, как запускать (без apt-get install valgrind) `./a.out`, чтобы печатаемый адрес всегда был тем же самым?

Comment: Ого, а зачем такое? Может быть, отключение [ASLR](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR) нужно (или как эта фича называется под линуксом?)

Comment: @VladD, Да! Вы первый. (это эксперимент, начало было в чате, Вы его пропустили)

Comment: Ну, надо, например diff-ом отладочную печать сравнивать.

Comment: Заинтригован, ушёл читать чат :)

Comment: Ага, прочитал. Будем считать, что я проиграл гуглу в пять раз. :) (Хотя рабочее время меня, наверное, извиняет.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Как верно замечено в комментариях, то, с чем вы столкнулись, называется [ASLR](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR) - рандомизация адресного пространства. Технология поддерживается во всех современных ОС.

Но, помимо поддержки в ОС, бинарники так же должны быть скомпилированы специальным образом. К примеру, у `GCC` есть [опции](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) для компиляции с поддержкой ASLR: `-fPIC/-fpic` и `-fPIE/-fpie`.

В Linux, поддержу ASLR на уровне ОС [можно отключить руками](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318315/how-can-i-temporarily-disable-aslr-address-space-layout-randomization):

```
sudo bash -c 'echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space'
```

и включить назад:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo 2 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space'
```

И наконец, в Linux есть утилита [`hardening-check`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/hardening-check.1.html), которая определяет, скомпилирован бинарник с поддержкой рандомизации или нет.

**UPD:**

Оказывается, есть целых 5 типов рандомизаций:

- Stack ASLR
- Libs/mmap ASLR
- Exec ASLR  -  вот этот тип задаётся флагами `fPIE` при компиляции
- brk ASLR
- VDSO ASLR

И в доках пишут, что для рандомизации malloc-ов используется [brk ASLR](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features#brk-aslr).

Т.е. получается, что для каких-то рандомизаций нужно указывать специальные флаги при компиляции программы, а какие-то работают по-умолчанию "из коробки". Так что, чтобы полностью исключить всякие рандомизации, нужно отключать ASLR на уровне ОС / в рамках сессии (`setarch $(uname -m) -RL bash`).

Comment: По крайней мере в x86_64 GNU/Linux `pic/pie` не нужны.

Comment: @avp почему не нужны?

Comment: @alexolut, потому что явление наблюдается и при трансляции без них.

Comment: А что показывает `hardening-check`?

Comment: Вы имели в виду вот это `avp@avp-ubu1:hash_misc$ gcc clist_test.c; hardening-check ./a.out 
./a.out:
 Position Independent Executable: no, normal executable!
 Stack protected: yes
 Fortify Source functions: no, only unprotected functions found!
 Read-only relocations: yes
 Immediate binding: no, not found!
avp@avp-ubu1:hash_misc$ ` ?

Comment: Именно: `Position Independent Executable: no, normal executable!`, а с флагами была бы рандомизация. Правда, оно ещё нашло какие-то релокаци: `Read-only relocations: yes`.

Comment: @avp обновил ответ.

Comment: И все же, у меня ведь *без всяких флагов компиляции* адреса рандомные. Может стоит как-то привести ответ в соответствии с этим фактом? (и тогда я его приму). / Кстати, самое простое для данной ситуации решение это -- `setarch $(uname -m) -R bash` и далее работа из под него, о чем Вы совершенно незаметно все же упомянули. А с какой целью Вы советуете включать 
      ADDR_COMPAT_LAYOUT (-L флаг в setarch)?

Comment: `-L` флаг рекомендуют в wiki gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Randomization

Comment: Флаги влияют на рандомизацию загрузки exe в память: `Each execution of a program that has been built with "-fPIE -pie" will get loaded into a different memory location.` А без флагов, он загружается всегда по одному и тому же адресу. Но даже загрузившись по тому же самому адресу, если в ОС включена рандомизация `brk`, вызов `malloc` будет возвращать разные адреса. С другой стороны, если рандомизация `brk` отключена, но exe скомпилирован с флагами рандомизации, `malloc` опять будет отдавать разные адреса. На это просто влияет сразу несколько факторов.

Comment: ОК. Если хотите, дополните ответ этими сведениями (не все же читают "простыню" комментариев). Хотя не уверен, что утверждение `бинарники так же должны быть скомпилированы специальным образом`, справедливо во всех случаях.

Comment: Кстати, если хотите, чтобы автор вопроса получал нотификацию о комментарии под Вашим ответом, вставляйте в нем @nick

Comment: @avp Про флаги всё справедливо. Чтобы работала рандомизация типа `Exec ASLR`, бинарники должны быть скомпилированы особым образом. Т.е., конкретно в вашем случае (рандомизация `malloc`), вам надо убедиться, что этих флагов нет и что в ОС отключена рандомизация типа `brk ASLR` (её можно отключать отдельно от остальных). Дабы убедиться в том, что флаги реально работают, скомпилируйте тест вот так `gcc -pie test.c`, отключите `brk ASLR` и посмотрите на результат.

Comment: @zed, что-то мы друг друга не понимаем. Я говорю, что программа скомпилированная `gcc x.c` (без *всяких* флагов), и запущенная в системе где *НИЧЕГО НЕ ВЫКЛЮЧАЛИ* выдает **рандомизированные адреса**. Вы с этим согласны?

Comment: Также я знаю, что тот же самый ./a.out, запускаемый  вот так `setarch \`uname -m\` -R ./a.out` выдает **одни и те же адреса**. А с этим Вы согласны?

Comment: @avp Полностью согласен. Но ведь возможные ситуации на этих 2 примерах не заканчиваются. Вы согласны, что если отключить **только** `brk ASLR`, то рандомизации `malloc` не будет, но если потом перекомпилировать бинарник с флагом `-pie`, она опять появится? И да, в конце ответа я как раз и указал, что для того, _чтобы полностью исключить всякие рандомизации, нужно отключать ASLR на уровне ОС_. А про флаги просто нужно помнить, что в некоторых кейсах они так же могут повлиять на рандомизацию. И конкретный кейс - если в системе отключена только `brk ASLR` рандомизация.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38272/discussion-between-avp-and-zed).

Comment: @zed, я все же внял просьбам системы и переехал в чат

Comment: ASLR ортогонально -fPIE и иже с ними.

Comment: @0andriy Это связанные вещи: нет флага - Exec ASLR не работает, есть - работает. [Built as PIE:](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features#pie) *All programs built as Position Independent Executables (PIE) with "-fPIE -pie" can take advantage of the exec ASLR.*

Comment: В вашем ответе есть предложение: *у GCC есть опции для компиляции с поддержкой ASLR: __-fPIC/-fpic__ и __-fPIE/-fpie__*. Вот оно неверно. Эти опгции не для этого. А вот то, что вы написали мне в комментарии верно. Понимаете о чём я?