# Почему у переменной разные адреса?

Tags: linux, c

Есть программа:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%s => %p\n", argv[1], getenv(argv[1]));
    return 0;
}
```

На сколько я понимаю, она должна принимать в качестве аргумента некую 
переменную и возвращать её адрес. Поясните, если не затруднит: почему при определении адреса одной и той же переменной у неё каждый раз новый адрес?

```
root@kali:~/Documents/ionet# ./getenv LANG
LANG => 0xbfe16bb8
root@kali:~/Documents/ionet# ./getenv LANG
LANG => 0xbfc06bb8
root@kali:~/Documents/ionet# ./getenv LANG
LANG => 0xbfa21bb8
```

Comment: По умолчанию (в целях безопасности (усложняет жизнь хакерам)) при запуске программы Linux располагает ее по разным (случайным) адресам

Comment: Каждый запуск у программы в ее распоряжении выделяется разный участок памяти.

Comment: Не ясна исходная посылка вопроса. С чего вы вообще взяли, что возвращаемый функцией `getenv` указатель должен быть стабильным? Это не переменная, которую вы сами объявили. Причем это, очевидно, величина времени выполнения, а не времени компиляции. Почему вы ожидаете от нее какой-то стабильности? Может существовать миллион причин, по которым эта величина может "плавать". Причем рандомизация раскладки памяти в рамках "антихакерских мер"  - далеко не первая приходящая на ум причина.

Comment: Если надо запускать в одних и тех же адресах, можете почитать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511574/232) или сразу попробовать запускать через `setarch $(uname -m) -RL bash`

Comment: @avp, спасибо за ответ! это как раз то, что нужно. Поместите, пожалуйста, ответ по форме, чтобы я мог отблагодарить Вас соответствующе)

Comment: @TakoKataka, да ладно (писать лень). Если разобравшись напишете самоответ, то тоже будет хорошо (и репы, наверное, срубите)

Comment: @avp, Вы могли бы даже скопировать Ваш комментарий, но только в качестве непосредственно ответа

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По умолчанию (вероятно в целях безопасности (усложняет жизнь хакерам)) при запуске программы Linux располагает ее по разным (случайным) адресам.

Если надо запускать в одних и тех же адресах, можете почитать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511574/232) (отличный ответ @zed на эту тему) или сразу попробовать запускать через `setarch $(uname -m) -RL bash`